# Websphere Liberty IBM Java SDK jconsole throwing error with com.ibm.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: acknowledgement timeout

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, jconsole

While trying to install the Mobilefirst server 7.1 with Webshpere Liberty 8.5.5.5 and IBM HTTP server 8.5.5, and using the IBM Java SDK 1.7 for Liberty I get the following exception when trying to access the Jconsole form the java installed inside the Liberty Profile --> Liberty --> Java --> Java_version --> bin --> ./jconsole.

> com.ibm.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: acknowledgement timeout from **90 on port **908.

Comment: Please learn how to post questions on stack overflow - you don't put the question and the answer in the same posting. There is a clear section that is for the question and a section for the answer. Edit your question accordingly and post the answer in the answer section.

Comment: I have edited the question to separate the answer from the question. Please don't be lazy next time.

Comment: Hi Idan, don't think people who are making post on stackoverflow are lazy,  I forgot to separate Q&A that's it. I could have make those changes without losing my reputations. Hope you also understand that.

Comment: I have upped my vote.

Comment: thanks a lot Idan...!!

Answer (score 1):

> The below is an edit of the answer that was written inside the question instead of as an answer

Oracle JDK should be used instead.

Start Jconsole and generate plugin for Mobilefirst server for the IBM HTTP Server.

- install the rpm of Oracle JDK and then go the installation directory and try to start the jconsole. If it's starting properly it means you can use this jconsole to generate plugin.
- Now next step is to get the MFP process in the jconsole to generate the plugin.  go to the Liberty server java installation folder where you will find the java.env file. this file contains the Default JDK installation path.
- Change the path to the Oracle JDK installation path and restart the server.
- Restart the Oracle JDK jconsole and then you can see the process in jconsole.
- then you can generate the plugin. the plugin can be found out in server folder.
- Later you can use this plugin-cfg.xml file to configure the IBM HTTP Server to Mobilefirst Server.

Comment: Hi Idan, you might be best in stackoverflow...but putting negative rating is also not good when somebody forgot how to post question and answer both on stackoverflow.